# Why am I getting multiple definition errors for this code?

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glfw

I have the following program where all I have is:

```
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
     glfwInit();
     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
     glfwTerminate();
}
```

And I got an undefined reference error for `glfwWindowHint`. So then I started linking against `glfw3` library.

After that I got a lot of multiple definition errors for functions I'm not even using:

```
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowTitle'|
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowPos'|
multiple definition of `glfwGetWindowSize'|
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowSize'|
multiple definition of `glfwIconifyWindow'|
multiple definition of `glfwRestoreWindow'|
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'|
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowCloseCallback'|
multiple definition of `glfwSetWindowRefreshCallback'|
multiple definition of `glfwPollEvents'|
multiple definition of `glfwWaitEvents'|
multiple definition of `glfwInit'|
multiple definition of `glfwTerminate'|
multiple definition of `glfwGetVersion'|
multiple definition of `_glfwStringInExtensionString'|
multiple definition of `glfwSwapBuffers'|
multiple definition of `glfwSwapInterval'|
multiple definition of `glfwExtensionSupported'|
multiple definition of `glfwGetProcAddress'|
multiple definition of `_glfwPlatformSetWindowTitle'|
multiple definition of `_glfwPlatformSetWindowPos'|
```

I took out a lot of lines from the errors, but they are all saying that these functions are first defined in `libglfw.a`, and then the multiple definition is coming from `libglfw3.a`. Yes, I have both of these files inside my `MinGW/lib` folder, but I don't understand why they are clashing with each other. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I am linking with:

```
mingw32-g++.exe ... -lglfw -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 -lglfw3
```

Comment: Share the command you use to invoke your compiler

Comment: You should only link to one of those libraries, not both.

Comment: @Appleshell I'm using Codeblocks. I set up the global compiler settings to link to `glfw` and `glfw3` at the same time, now I don't know how to undo it :(

Comment: @templateboy http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/

Comment: @Appleshell When I go to the linker tab to try to delete them, the list of the libraries are not there, but when I look at the build log, they're all there.

Comment: @templateboy There are two linker tabs, one time at the project settings, and one time the global settings.

Comment: @Appleshell I'll figure something out. :)

Comment: @Appleshell I figured it out. The linking policy was set to `"Append target options to project options"` when it should have been `"Use target options only"`. If you would like to make an answer about linking with only one of the libraries, I will accept it.

Comment: Your header is wrong - shouldn't it be `<GLFW/glfw3.h>`?

Comment: @BrettHale No. Inside the MinGW folder there is a subdirectory called `GL`. That's where I put `glfw3.h`. One could change the name if they want however.

Comment: @templateboy - Ah. I was thinking of my own unix-land directory layout.